# promql regex with label_replace returns blank value when regex contain \w

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have this metric being returned

```
my_sqldatabase{aggregation="maximum", instance="sql-metrics-exporter", interval="PT5M", job="metrics-sqldatabase", id="/sub/1291-3432432-e432/mydatabase"}
```

I want to extract the last bit after / (i.e. mydatabase) for a new label called db and have tried the below

```
label_replace(my_sqldatabase{metric="storage_percent", aggregation="maximum"}, "db", "$1", "id", "([\\w]+$)")
```

I always end up with a blank value db like so or an error

```
my_sqldatabase{aggregation="maximum", db="" instance="sql-metrics-exporter", interval="PT5M", job="metrics-sqldatabase", id="/sub/1291-3432432-e432/mydatabase"}
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I've tried, ([\w]+$), [\w]+$, [\w]+$, ([\\w]+$) and either get an error or blank value. It seems to be `\` that's causing the issue but I can't figure out why or how to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
label_replace(my_sqldatabase{metric="storage_percent", aggregation="maximum"}, "db", "$1", "id", ".+/(.+)")
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Any ideas why \w causes issues and if so how to get around it?

Comment: The "\w" doesn't match the slashes ("/"). You can use this: ".+/(\\w+)". It will work.